# вставка в односвязный список

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вставить один односвязный список в другой, начиная с индекса.

Я понимаю то, что если будет вставка второго списка в первый начиная с хвоста, то хвост мы поменяем но конец второго списка
Что должна принимать функция, реализующая этот метод: только индекс?
Нужно ли в методе создавать новый третий список, который будет содержать первый и второй или можно в первый просто вставить во второй?

```
class Node{
    constructor(value,next=null) {
        this.value=value
        this.next=next
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null
        this.tail = null
    }
```

Моя нерабочая реализация:

```
 function insert(index){

        let currentNode=list.head
        let newNode=new(Node)
        while (currentNode.next){
            --index
            currentNode=currentNode.next
            if (index===0){
                let curNode2=list2.head
                while(curNode2.next){
                    newNode.value=curNode2.value
                    newNode.next=curNode2.next
                    curNode2.next=newNode
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

пример входных данных:

односвязный список 1: head 0 1 2 tail

односвязный список 2: head A B C tail

пример выходных данных:

вызываем function insert(1)

результат: односвязный список 1 становится: head 0 1 A B C 2 tail

Comment: и при чем тут вставка с хвоста? Нашли в списке 1 нужный индекc, - узел `x`. Сделали `list2->tail->next = x->next` и `x->next = list2->head` и все. Разве что проверить, что list2 не пуст, и что x вообще найден, и у него тоже next не пуст.

Comment: вместо дублирования вопроса достаточно было отредактировать предыдущий.

Comment: определение списка тоже кодом вставь, а не картинкой

Comment: в односвязном списке `tail` - не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

функция size() возвращает размер списка

реализация:

```
 function insert(index) {
    
        if (list.head === null || list2.head === null || index > list.size()) return null
    
        if (index > 0 && index < list.size()) {
    
            let currentNode = list.head
    
            for (let count = 0; count != index - 1; count++) {
                currentNode = currentNode.next
            }
    
            let tempNode = currentNode.next
    
            currentNode.next = list2.head
    
            currentNode = list.head
    
            while (currentNode.next) {
                currentNode = currentNode.next
            }
            currentNode.next = tempNode
        }
    
        if (index === 0) {
            let currentNode = list2.head
            while (currentNode) {
                list.insertBefore(index, currentNode.value)
                currentNode = currentNode.next
                ++index
            }
        }
    
        if (index===list.size()){
    
            let currentNode=list2.head
    
            while (currentNode){
                list.append(currentNode.value)
                currentNode=currentNode.next
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: это ответ или дополнение к вопросу? Откуда взялся метод `size`? его нет в вопросе

Comment: @Grundy исправил, теперь это ответ